# Print list without spaces

Tags: python, list, printing, python-3.x

I have this code here. I want to print a list without spaces. Here `l` is a list with 3 elements that I am trying to print:

```
>>> l=[]
>>> l.append(5)
>>> l.append(6)
>>> l.append(7)
>>> print(l)
```

I get in the output:

```
[5, 6, 7]
```

but I want to get:

```
[5,6,7]
```

What should I add to the syntax in `append` or in `print` to print the list without spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use something like:

```
print('[{0}]'.format(','.join(map(str, l))))
```

Comment: with this approach don't u get a string at the end?i think he asks for a list withoud spaces.

Comment: @vaggelas he has a list of integers and wants to print it without spaces.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the result if it isn't too big:

```
print(repr(l).replace(' ', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the list elements.

```
print("[" + ",".join([str(i) for i in l]) + "]")
```

Comment: `.join` expects a list of strings

Comment: its not working for me... its raise exception:
'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found'

Answer (score 1):

You could convert it to a string and then replace the spaces. E.g:

```
print ("{}".format(l)).replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to use the old syntax for string formatting. Use http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax instead.